Automatic Scroll with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback Works on iOS but Not on Android
I'm working on a Flutter app and I'm trying to implement automatic scrolling to a specific index in a ListView after the widget tree has been built. I'm using the following code to achieve this:
dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _animateToIndex(10); // Index of the item I want to scroll to
});

Here is the _animateToIndex function:
void _animateToIndex(int index) {
  _scrollController.animateTo(
    index * _itemHeight, // Assuming each item has the same height
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  );
}

This works perfectly on iOS, but on Android, the scroll does not happen. I've confirmed that the _animateToIndex method is being called on both platforms.

Try to use SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback instead of WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback. As SchedulerBinding schedules work during the post-frame phase of the widget lifecycle.
